# PFQuery categorizing results into multilevel arrays

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to do a multiple `PFQuery` and storing the data properly.

My plan is to query for group members in my `Group`
I am looking for the key `member`. It gives me an array of `objectIds`. Then I want to query in my `_User` class for their picture with key `firstImage`. Displaying the data is not the problem, just getting it the right way.

The data needs to be stored considering it's groups. This is what i tried so far:

```
  let fetchGroupsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Group")
        fetchGroupsQuery.whereKey("member", equalTo: objectID!)
        fetchGroupsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil
            {
            }
         else {

    if let objects = objects {
    self.memberPhotos.removeAll()

       for object in objects {

    if let member = object["member"] as? [String]
   {
        // returns array of objectIds
            for user in member 
           {
              // returns single ids                          
              self.groupIds.append(user)

    let photoQuery = PFUser.query()
    photoQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: user)
photoQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results, error) -> Void in
       if error != nil {
     // ....  
    }
       else {
    self.memberPhotos.removeAll()
      if let results = results 
      {
          for result in results 
          {
               if result["firstImage"] != nil
              {
                 self.memberPhotos.append(result["firstImage"])
              }
         }
     }
   }})
  }   
}
```

My idea was to store the data within an array of arrays.
So that I can later go into `array[indexPath.row]` to get the array I need to loop through in order to get the right group pictures.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two separate queries function: 
1) **to get their ID's**
2) **for their pictures.**

For the first query: **what you need to change?**

Your `objectID` array  should be of type of `NSMutableArray` because in order to fetch their info you should use the constraint **whereKey containedIn** not **whereKey equalTo**
and for that constraint you should downcast your `NSMutableArray to type AnyObject`.

Also change the **Type of your groupIds to NSMutableArray**, then append your array.

For the Second query:

Since your groupIds Type is already NSMutableArray just cast it to AnyObject,then use the **whereKey containedIn**

> Note: It would be better to download all images before appending your
>   array. So you have the option of using `struct` or `class`(easier to
>   group data to its owner) then create an array of that data
>   structure.Where it because easier to populate your UI.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I am having an issue checking for "containedIn", since my query didn't finish yet, but xCode is checking for the elements in my Array which is 0. Is there a way to overcome this?